# Selenium how to get variable from script removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, selenium

```
<script id="[randomid]">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
    var quiz=new Quiz();
    //// some logic here
    document.getElementById('[randomid]').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('[randomid]'));
});
</script>
```

I am trying to get variable quiz in selenium and execute some functions on it. But problem is that before I can do anything it is already removed from dom and it is working in bakground. I can print this object in chrome console using this: queryObjects(Quiz). But it just prints and doesn't return object. So I am looking for function which for example would return all variables of choosen type, or would somehow restore this script to dom. Maybe it is possible to prevent from removing script from dom.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used Selenium Wire to intercept response and change it. I added `document.quiz = quiz;` after initialization.